# How to copy a file into xcode project but not to the root folder

Tags: xcode, project-management

When dragging a file into the project explorer in xcode, you are asked if you want to copy the files into the project if needed. if you check that box the file is copied into the root folder of the project.

is there any way to explore where you want to copy the files into, i mean, is it possible to copy the file into subfolders of the root folder?

Answer (score 0):

Dragging files in you will usually copy them to the project resources folder.

If you want to be able to access them from your app, you might be better adding the files to the mainbundle or documentation folders.